# After reboot, a android SQLite file locksettings.db-shm was found unlabeled

Tags: android, sqlite, shared-memory, selinux

I'm developing on Android 5.0 now, and I get these logs several times just after the device rebooted in low-power state(I'm not sure if low-power is relevant here).

I don't familiar with SQLite, but I have gone through the flow of ext4 file create, read, and how does selinux label the inode, and I don't see how can a ext4 file inode's xattr be corrupted.

In normal, it should appear like this:

```
u:object_r:system_data_file:s0 locksettings.db-shm
u:object_r:system_data_file:s0 locksettings.db-wal
```

I'll paste logs later.

Any help is appreciated..Thank you

---Scenario 1:--

```
**kmsg:**
<12>[   26.034851s][pid:2758,cpu3,logd.auditd]type=1400 audit(1425430396.379:7): 
avc: denied { write } for pid=3244 comm="system_server" name="locksettings.db-   shm" dev="mmcblk0p40" ino=430823 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

**logcat:**
08:53:16.369  3244  3244 E SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 28606 of [9491ba7d73]
E SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:28606: (13) open(/data/system/locksettings.db-shm) - 
E SQLiteLog: (14) unable to open database file
E SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 28606 of [9491ba7d73]
E SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:28606: (13) open(/data/system/locksettings.db-shm) - 
E SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/system/locksettings.db'.
E SQLiteDatabase: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file(Sqlite code 14): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode,(OS error - 13:Permission denied)
E SQLiteDatabase:   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
E SQLiteDatabase:   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
E SQLiteDatabase:   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:634)
E SQLiteDatabase:   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:320)
E SQLiteDatabase:   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:291)
E SQLiteDatabase:   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
```

--Scenario 2:--

```
**kmsg:**
11:58:55.334 <6>[   26.980468s][pid:3299,cpu4,system_server]SELinux:  Context  is not valid (left unmapped).
11:58:55.334 <12>[   26.980743s][pid:2844,cpu0,logd.auditd]type=1400 audit(1425009535.319:5): avc: denied { write } for pid=3299 comm="system_server" name="locksettings.db-wal" dev="mmcblk0p40" ino=16423 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
11:58:55.334 <12>[   26.986572s][pid:2844,cpu0,logd.auditd]type=1400 audit(1425009535.319:6): avc: denied { write } for pid=3299 comm="system_server" name="locksettings.db-wal" dev="mmcblk0p40" ino=16423 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

**logcat:**
11:58:55.319  3299  3299 E SQLiteLog: (283) recovered 10 frames from WAL file /data/system/locksettings.db-wal
```

Comment: Noticed in scenario 2,  "SELinux:  Context  is not valid", inode's  context.len !=0, but context.str is NULL or cannot be formatted.